# Error while deploying Spring Batch in Weblogic BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository'

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, spring-batch

I want to test Spring Batch, but I need to use it without maven or gradle because there are some restrictions in the network. I read a [tutorial on spring](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/)  and the [spring documentation to configure a Job](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html), but I get an "Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository'"

This question [has been asked already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492150/necessary-jars-for-spring-batch) without an answer.

I'm using Jeveloper and Weblogic 12.1.3.0.0.

My project has the following dependencies which I get from another project configured with Eclipse Maven:

```
com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
hsqldb-2.3.3.jar
javax.batch-api-1.0.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
jettison-1.2.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
logback-core-1.1.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
snakeyaml-1.14.jar
spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.j
spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.4.7.jar
```

The java classes are:

JobLauncherController.java

```
package batch;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class JobLauncherController {
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @RequestMapping("/jobLauncher.html")
    public String handle() throws Exception{
        System.err.println("Hello Spring Batch!");
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        return "redirect:index";
    }
}
```

MyTasklet.java

```
package batch;

import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;

public class MyTasklet implements Tasklet{

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        System.err.println("¡Hello World TASKLET!");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
  <display-name>Test Batch App</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>testBatch</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet> 

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>testBatch</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
       <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags/form</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/spring-form.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

testBatch-servlet.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="batch"/>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>
     <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
                class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager"></beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="jobRepository"
                class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <beans:property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
        <beans:property name="taskExecutor">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="myTasklet" class="batch.MyTasklet"></beans:bean>
    <job id="job">
        <step id="test">
            <tasklet ref="myTasklet"/>
        </step>
    </job>
</beans:beans>
```

And last but not least, the stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherController': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher batch.JobLauncherController.jobLauncher; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeweblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher batch.JobLauncherController.jobLauncher; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:105)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:240)
        ... 66 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
        ... 68 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        ... 83 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:100)
        at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:814)
        at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(GenericTypeResolver.java:164)
        at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveReturnType(GenericTypeResolver.java:101)
        at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:138)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:386)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        ... 92 more
    <21/10/2015 02:01:45 AM COT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "testBatch" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "testBatch".
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherController': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher batch.JobLauncherController.jobLauncher; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher batch.JobLauncherController.jobLauncher; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:105)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:240)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testBatch-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    > 
    WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
    WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
    <21/10/2015 02:01:45 AM COT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "32136025790510" for task "15". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException"
    weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    > 
    <21/10/2015 02:01:45 AM COT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 9 task for the application "TestBatch".> 
    <21/10/2015 02:01:45 AM COT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "TestBatch".> 
    <21/10/2015 02:01:45 AM COT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
    weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:95)
        at
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I think is something related to Weblogic 12.1.3.0(12c). I made a web project in Netbeans (with and without Maven), and these work fine. Maybe Weblogic requires some special configuration?

the following jars were generated with netbeans and maven (spring-batch-core, 3.0.5.RELEASE and spring-webmvc, 4.0.5.RELEASE) [as Malguna said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33253846/4253946)

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
javax.batch-api-1.0.jar
jettison-1.2.jar
spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.4.7.jar
```

**UPDATE II**
I made a workaround to this issue, although It doesn't tackle the real problem It let me keep forward in what I really want. That is, making Jdeveloper (12c), Weblogic and Spring Batch work together.

I add a jobRepository and a datasource whit hsqldb in the testBatch-servlet.xml. After that, add hsqldb-2.3.3.jar and spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar

```
    <beans:bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao"/>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao" />
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao"/>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>  <!-- Extra constructor argument -->
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao"/>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch. You have spring 3 libraries `spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar` along with spring 4 libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Fran. I was seeing the spring repo but I think They handle different versions. See [Spring framework](http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/) and [batch project](http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-core/) handle different versions of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I need to use **Spring Batch 2.2.7 together with Weblogic 12.1.3**.

I thought that The error was configuration in my xml file but It seems that is a support issue with weblogic, because [I found a similar error later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289153/error-creating-job-in-spring-batch).

The dependency list:

```
 aopalliance-1.0.jar
 commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
 jettison-1.1.jar
 spring-aop-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
 spring-batch-core-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar
 spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar
 spring-beans-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
 spring-context-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
 spring-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
 spring-expression-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
 spring-retry-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar
 spring-tx-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
 spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
 spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
 xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
 xstream-1.3.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get an `java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException` this means there are some class that is trying to use a method by means of reflection, but it has malformed the parameters needed to call it.

This is common when you have wrong dependencies, that is, when you are using wrong dependency version and thus a dependent method has changed its parameters list.

I created a void pom.xml with only `spring-batch-core` version `3.0.5.RELEASE` and it gives me the following dependencies list:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
javax.batch-api-1.0.jar
jettison-1.2.jar
spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.4.7.jar
```

So as you can see, you are using spring version `4.1.8.RELEASE` instead `4.0.5.RELEASE`. This could be the cause of your error.

Please review your hand managed dependencies to fit those I shown you. Maybe it resolves your problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I did what you said, but the same error persists. The strange thing is that It fails to instantiate jobRepository  org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean and org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager are in the same versioned jars

Comment: Another thing, I thought that jobRepository had to be an implementation of  JobRepository (as [SimpleJobRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/SimpleJobRepository.html)) but [MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html) is not.

Comment: I followed your strategy and finally I made it work, I need to use Spring Batch 2.2.7 together with Weblogic 12.1.3.