# Weblogic failing with error : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

When the application is deployed over Weblogic 12.1.3 getting following error at the startup

```
Feb 6, 2019 9:05:51,896 PM PST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationEventMulticaster' defined in class path resource [META-INF/common.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'pool' while setting bean property 'taskExecutor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pool': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.init.PolicyManager com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.ThreadPoolExecutor.g; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'policyManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.init.PolicyManager.jF; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler.z; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigurationObject': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.CentralAuthenticationService com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject.Q; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationEventMulticaster' defined in class path resource [META-INF/common.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'pool' while setting bean property 'taskExecutor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pool': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.init.PolicyManager com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.ThreadPoolExecutor.g; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'policyManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.init.PolicyManager.jF; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler.z; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigurationObject': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.CentralAuthenticationService com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject.Q; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pool': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.init.PolicyManager com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.ThreadPoolExecutor.g; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'policyManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.init.PolicyManager.jF; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler.z; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigurationObject': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.CentralAuthenticationService com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject.Q; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.init.PolicyManager com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.ThreadPoolExecutor.g; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'policyManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.init.PolicyManager.jF; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler.z; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigurationObject': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.CentralAuthenticationService com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject.Q; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'policyManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.init.PolicyManager.jF; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler.z; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigurationObject': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.CentralAuthenticationService com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject.Q; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.init.PolicyManager.jF; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler.z; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigurationObject': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.CentralAuthenticationService com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject.Q; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler.z; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigurationObject': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.CentralAuthenticationService com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject.Q; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.services.schedulers.Scheduler.z; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigurationObject': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.CentralAuthenticationService com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject.Q; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfigurationObject': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.CentralAuthenticationService com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject.Q; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.CentralAuthenticationService com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.SecurityConfigurationObject.Q; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/authentication.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error initializing OpenSAML library.
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.security.service.central.AbstractCentralAuthenticationService.<clinit>(AbstractCentralAuthenticationService.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.opensaml.xml.ConfigurationException: Can not create instance of org.opensaml.soap.soap11.impl.BodyBuilder
        at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.createClassInstance(XMLConfigurator.java:359)
        at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.initializeObjectProviders(XMLConfigurator.java:235)
        at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:181)
        at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:165)
        at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:142)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opensaml.soap.soap11.impl.BodyBuilder
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Verified spring batch deployed for application :

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
jettison-1.3.7.jar
spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.4.8.jar
```

As given in the following thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253498/error-while-deploying-spring-batch-in-weblogic-beancreationexception-error-crea

For application Weblogic is showing following error :

```
**** Error occurred while destroying Security Service *****

<Feb 6, 2019 9:05:51,945 PM PST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.eqtechnologic.eqube.eQInitListener failed: java.lang.NullPointerException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.ServerStartupInitialization.destroySecurityService(ServerStartupInitialization.java:259)
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.eQInitListener.b(eQInitListener.java:70)
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.eQInitListener.contextDestroyed(eQInitListener.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:706)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Feb 6, 2019 9:05:51,992 PM PST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "eQubeMI".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opensaml.soap.soap11.impl.BodyBuilder
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opensaml.soap.soap11.impl.BodyBuilder
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

If the same war is deployed over another server then this war is working, but failing on this server only.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.opensaml.soap.soap11.impl.BodyBuilder
>           at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
>           at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
>           at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)

Seem that Weblogic 's class-loader loads `OpenSAML` jar from its internal modules rather than load from the WAR. And apparently , that `OpenSAML` jar shipped with Weblogic is incompatible with the one that is required by your app.

You can search how to make Weblogic to have higher load JARs priority from the deployed WAR than its internal module.On the other hand , one of the [trick](https://docs.alfresco.com/saml1.0/concepts/saml-known-issues.html) is simply remove / rename the OpenSAML jar shipped with Weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

[WebLogic Filtering Classloader Fails After Upgrade (Doc ID 2269375.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2269375.1)

Use the  section in the application's weblogic-application.xml file to filter any needed configuration files to be loaded from the application rather than from the system. For example, adding these entries resolved the OpenSAML problem:

```
<prefer-application-resources>
...
  <resource-name>soap11-config.xml</resource-name>
  <resource-name>schema/xmltooling-config.xsd</resource-name>
</prefer-application-resources>
```